# replaceWith only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replacewith

Replace with is only working once, I am outputting the data and this is updating so I know data has changed, however it is not writing the new data to the div appart from the 1st time.

```
$( "#searchboxform" ).keyup(function() {
    var forminfo = $('#searchboxform').val();
     $.get("searchliveresults.php?search="+forminfo,function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    $("#searchresults").replaceWith(data);

  });
alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
```

Comment: If the original element was replaced with a new element, would the selector you have still match the new element? Can you post the new content, `data`?

Comment: What's `data`? Is it a piece of HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceWith(data)` is replacing the entire element when I think you want the container `#searchresults` to persist. Change `replaceWith` to `html` like so:

```
$("#searchboxform").keyup(function () {
    var forminfo = $('#searchboxform').val();
    $.get("searchliveresults.php?search=" + forminfo, function (data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        $("#searchresults").html(data);

    });
    alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");
});
```